# error running c:/bitmani/wordpress/php/php -v child killed unknown signal

Tags: php, wordpress

I had tried to install Bitmani wordpress stack on my laptop(win 8.1).Due to network issues the installation aborted abnormally and I could not repair the software. When tried to new install it is showing "error running c:/bitmani/wordpress/php/php -v child killed unknown signal".I tried all solutions available on internet but nothing worked. Log file is given below

> ```
> Log started 06/11/2019 at 23:21:14
> Preferred installation mode : qt
> Trying to init installer in mode qt
> Mode qt successfully initialized
> [23:21:26] [mysql:initialization] Running action list...
> [23:22:00] [mysql:pre-installation] Running action list...
> Current working directory changed to C:\Users\india\Downloads
> Launching https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress/cloud?utm_source=bitnami&utm_medium=installer&utm_campaign=wordpress
> Preparing to Install
> Preparing to Install
> [23:22:58] [mysql:ready-to-install] Running action list...
> Unpacking files
> Unpacking files
> Unpacking files
> Unpacking files
> Unpacking files
> [23:25:49] [mysql:folder] Running action list...
> Unpacking files
> Executing C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.1-0/php/vcredist_x64_2017.exe /q
> Script exit code: 1638
>
> Script output:
>
>
>  Script stderr:
>  Program ended with an error exit code
>
>  Error running C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.1-0/php/vcredist_x64_2017.exe /q: Program ended with an error exit code
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today. Here's the solution I found.

1. Go to install directory/php/ and find the `vcredist_x64_2017.exe` and run it. In my case, I had a previous installation. Therefore, I repaired my version.
2. Open the `php.exe` on the same folder and it should open without any error.
3. Exit the bitnami installation and clean all the folders.
4. Run the bitnami installation again.